# vue-apollo: GraphQL queries only run when using <ApolloQuery> tags. Never works in script code. this.$apollo.queries is empty

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I know I'm probably missing something really super basic here, I'm trying to run a graphql query with vue-apollo... if I use  tags, it works fine

If I try to run queries from inside my  code, like in the basic examples in the docs (links below) then nothing happens.  The server never receives any request, and this.$apollo.queries is empty.)

Basic examples from the docs:

- https://akryum.github.io/vue-apollo/guide/apollo/#queries
- https://vue-apollo.netlify.com/guide/apollo/queries.html#simple-query

I've defined the query in the "apollo" property/object... how do I actually execute it when the page loads?  Note that I'm using typescript, which is why it's using a "`get apollo()`" method.

Here's my code...

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'

  export default class List extends Vue {

    myQueryName='my default value';

    get apollo() {
      return {
        myQueryName: {
          query: require('../graphql/listMeta.graphql'),
          // prefetch: true <-- tried with and without this
        }
      }
    }

  }
</script>

<template>
  <div>

    <!-- THIS DOESN"T WORK ... -->
    queries are: {{this.$apollo.queries}} <!-- THIS JUST SHOWS AN EMPTY OBJECT: {} -->
    <hr>
    myQueryName value is: {{myQueryName}} <!-- THIS JUST SHOWS "my default value"  -->

    <hr>
    <!--
    THIS DOES WORK...
    <ApolloQuery :query="this.apollo.myQueryName.query" >
      <template slot-scope="{ result: { loading, error, data } }"></template>
    </ApolloQuery>
    -->
  </div>
</template>
```

Note that this.$apollo.queries is empty in the template, probably a clue... but still no idea why its empty. From the docs and examples I've seen it should be populated from my `get apollo` data method.

Looks basically the same as https://github.com/OniVe/vue-apollo-typescript-example/blob/master/pages/index.vue as far as I can tell, I don't know what the difference is.

I've tried rebuilding the project from scratch multiple times (with and without nuxt), over teh course of months and many different versions of vue/nuxt/apollo/vue-apollo... the queries never run (from memory) unless I use  tags.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `@Component` decorator, it is needed to set initial properties of Vue component, so `vue-apollo` can detect it when component created and make a smartquery property.

```js
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator'
import listMetaDocument from '../graphql/listMeta.gql'

@Component({
  name: 'List',
  apollo: {
    listMeta: {
      query: listMetaDocument
    },
  },
})
export default class List extends Vue { }
```